# .NET - Retrieve attribute from controller context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, controller

I have a controller `insert` action:

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
Function InsertObject(<Bind(Exclude:="Id")> <ModelBinder(GetType(CustomModelBinder))> ByVal object As SomeObject) As ActionResult

End Function
```

And i have a `CustomModelBinder` class with a `BindModel` implementation:

```
Public Function BindModel( _
ByVal controllerContext As System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, _ 
ByVal bindingContext As System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext) As Object Implements System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder.BindModel
    For Each s In HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Keys
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(s & ": " & HttpContext.Current.Request.Form(s) & "<br />")
    Next

    HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
End Function
```

As you can see I have a `controllerContext` and  a `ModelBindingContext` available.

**How do I get the: `<Bind(Exclude:="Id")>` part inside the `BindModel` implementation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reimplemented the issue. Question became obsolete.